# проблема создания веб сервиса при помощи сервлета

Tags: java, mysql, веб-сервер

дали задание создать сервис для сайта покупки билетов, при этом нет исходника этого сайта. Есть документация API со входными данными для покупки билета(место, id_покупки) и написать все это на java сервлете не имею ни малейшего понятия как это создать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: используй спринг бут:) он практически все сделает за тебя

Answer (score 2):

1. Юзер открывает браузер.
2. Дёргается сервлет и с API вытаскивает список фильмов, в которых есть список сеансов и карты залов.
3. Сервлет отображает юзеру этот список.
4. Юзер жамкает по кнопкам и сервлет получает данные сеанса и места.
5. Эти данные сервлет шлёт к API и тот, видимо, как-то перенаправляет на сайт платёжной системы.
6. Всё.

Comment: Тут ещё тысяча деталей, но общий принцип такой.

Comment: думаю данному автору стоит сообщить, что сервлет - это контроллер.(MVC), чтобы не пугался:)

Comment: @БорисовМакс, ну, я про это не знаю) С сервлетами дел очень мало имел)